# Exponent to maximize the expression $log_b \left(a\frac{b-1}{b^k-1}\right)$

Tags: optimization, logarithms

Given $ a, b \in \mathbb N $, how to maximize the expression
$$ log_b \left(a\frac{b-1}{b^k-1}\right) \in \mathbb N $$
Put differently, what is the minimum $k \in \mathbb N $ verifying
$$ a\frac{b-1}{b^k-1} = b^p $$
with $ p \in \mathbb N $.

Comment: Taking the log might be a mistake, note that $\frac{b-1}{b^k -1} = \frac{1}{b^{k-1} + b^{k-2} + \dots + 1}$ then we have $a = b^{k + p -1} + b^{k + p -2} + \dots + b^p$

Comment: Such it is the expression I need to maximize, but with or without log, what would be the expression for $k$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$a(b-1)=b^p(b^k-1)$$
Since $b^p$ divides $a(b-1)$ and $b^p$ and $b-1$ are coprime, $b^p$ divides $a$. In fact,
$$a=b^p(1+b+\cdots+b^{k-1})$$

So, the value of $k$, if it exists, depends entirely of the given numbers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Agreed, but what is the expression for that dependence? I need the formula obtaining $k$ from $a$ and $b$.